# jmeter recorder: how to clear and start recording again without creating a new project

Tags: jmeter

When you setup the jmeter recorder template, and hit record, then stop, it shows a lot of requests in the "HTTP(S) test script Recorder" results tree, and presumably the same results in the "Recording Controller" results tree.

This will include a lot of garbage that has nothing to do with the pages visited in the browser (e.g. skype, MSN etc).

Is there a way to clear what you have recorded, and start recording again (e.g. with a new filter)?

Under "recording controller" there is a "clear all the recorded samples", but I cant find anything like this under "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder".

If I "clear all recorded samples" in the "Recording controller", then start the recording again, nothing happens - it doesnt seem to record anything (even if filter has not changed).  Do I need to re-install the CA each time I run the test script recorder? I was assuming it would use the same one for at least 7 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're looking for "Clear All" option available under "Run" main menu entry:

[image]

You don't need to re-install JMeter's MITM certificate, it's valid for 7 days since creation, if you don't want to re-import it each week you can amend [`proxy.cert.validity` JMeter property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert) and increase its expiry date to whatever number of days you want. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) article for more information on JMeter Properties and ways of setting and overriding them

With regards to "garbage", it should be possible to discard it using "Requests Filtering" tab of the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder:

[image]